# Missing number error in pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, errors, missing, number

I got a weird error when I use add `yshift=-1mm` to my plot. The error does not appear when I use positive value. The shift works, but looking at the red error is really annoying.

> Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{figure}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[]

\begin{axis}[
    legend cell align={left},
    legend pos = north east,
    compat=1.3,
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.4\textwidth,
    title={Vývoj tržní a výkupní ceny elektřiny},
    xlabel={Rok},
    ylabel={Cena [Kč/kWh]},
    ymin=0, ymax=14,
    xmin=2008, xmax=2022,
    xticklabel style={xshift=2mm,yshift=-1mm,rotate=45,anchor=east, /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    xtick={2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022},
    ytick={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,15},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    ultra thick,
    color=red,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (2008,1.6)(2009,1.4)(2010,1.2)(2011,1.3)(2012,1.3)(2013,1.1)(2014,0.9)(2015,0.85)(2016,0.6)(2017,0.8)(2018,1)(2019,1.3)(2020,1.2)(2021,2.8)(2022,4)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Tržní cena}

\addplot[
    ultra thick,
    color=green,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (2008,13.5)(2009,12.8)(2010,12.2)(2011,5.5)(2012,6.2)(2013,2.8)(2014,0)(2015,0)(2016,0)(2017,0)(2018,0)(2019,0)(2020,0)(2021,0)(2022,0)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Výkupní cena (z FV)}
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \caption[Vývoj průměrné tržní ceny elektřiny a výkupní ceny elektřiny z FV]{Vývoj průměrné tržní ceny elektřiny a výkupní ceny elektřiny z FV mezi lety 2008 a 2022 \footnotemark[2]}
    \label{fig:Vyvojcen1}
    
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. Please, what is the complete compilable code?

Comment: Your code, once added a `\documentclass{}` and loading the necessary packages, works just fine. I cannot reproduce your problem. `yshift=-1mm` in `xticklabel` does not cause any problems.

Comment: Could you tell us what the error says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned other in comments, after completing your code fragment to small, compilable document, compilation doesn't throw any error.

However, you can change x labels anchor to `north east` and omit `xshift` and `yshift`. Also your data can collect in table and by this make  diagram code a bit shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}  

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\pgfplotstableread{
d       A       B
2008    1.6     13.5
2009    1.4     12.8
2010    1.2     12.2
2011    1.3     5.5
2012    1.3     6.2
2013    1.1     2.8
2014    0.9     0
2015    0.85    0
2016    0.6     0
2017    0.8     0
2018    1       0
2019    1.3     0
2020    1.2     0
2021    2.8     0
2022    4       0
}{\datatable}
    
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,
    height=0.4\textwidth,
    legend cell align={left},
    legend pos = north east,
    title={Vývoj tržní a výkupní ceny elektřiny},
    xlabel={Rok},
    ylabel={Cena [Kč/kWh]},
    ymin=0, ymax=14,
    xmin=2008, xmax=2022,
    xticklabel style={inner sep=2pt, rotate=45, anchor=north east, 
                      /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
    xtick=data,
    ytick={0,2,...,14},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    every axis plot post/.append style={ultra thick}
]
\addplot[color=red,]
    table[x=d, y=A] {\datatable};
\addplot[color=green]
    table[x=d, y=B] {\datatable};
    \legend{Tržní cena, Výkupní cena (z FV)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \caption[Vývoj průměrné tržní ceny elektřiny a výkupní ceny elektřiny z FV]{Vývoj průměrné tržní ceny elektřiny a výkupní ceny elektřiny z FV mezi lety 2008 a 2022 \footnotemark[2]}
    \label{fig:Vyvojcen1}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]